# How do I assign tasks in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs, tasks

It used to be possible to assign a task to a user in Google Docs by [simply mentioning a user in a comment](https://www.kimbley.com/blog/8/5/2017/how-to-assign-tasks-to-others-in-google-docs), but this no longer works.

Is there a new way to do this? Has the feature been removed?
How do I assign tasks in Google Docs in 2019?

Answer (score 2):

One **used to** be able to assign a task just by typing someone's name.

> ### 2019 Update

That way has changed.

- **You will now be given the option to assign a Task *(Action Item)* as soon as and only if you type either the `@` or `+` characters.**

[image: Assign a task in Google Docs 2019 update]

- **Following that you can choose who to assign the task to**.

[image: Assign a task in Google Docs 2019 update]

> ***Pro Tips***

- You can use the same technique in **Google Spreadsheets** as well as **Google Slides**.
- You can even assign a Task or Todo **action to yourself** *(as a reminder)*.

[image: Assign an Action Item to yourself]

- In your **Google Drive, search/filter** files via the `Search Options` dropdown using the operator: **`followup:actionitems`**

[image: Google Drive search operator followup:actionitems]

Comment: Please also check the *updated Pro Tips*.

Comment: You can still do this by simply typing a users name: that's not the issue, it seems. It turns out that you can't (maybe never could?) assign an issue for an existing comment. [These features only work when the steps to add an issue are taken in a fresh comment, before it is first saved.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/135822/140429) Once it's saved, issues won't assign.

Comment: _"...that's not the issue..."_.  Then why ask  _"How do I assign tasks..."_. Which is what my answer is about. Next, instead of accepting, you much later post your own answer, NOT answering your question!! I'm lost. Nevertheless, please remember as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and maybe [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) so others can benefit as well. Anyway. I do hope my answer will be useful to someone.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that it turns out not to be the issue I was experiencing. No worries.

Answer (score 1):

This can indeed be done by simply mentioning a users name, either by typing it or by typing a `+` or `@` followed by their name or e-mail address. *However* this will not work for an existing comment, either when editing or when replying. It only works when creating a new comment.